# List of Leaves in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to create a list of leaves of a tree in Racket.

```
(define-struct (Some T)
  ([value : T]))

    (define-type (Option T)
      (U 'None (Some T)))

    (define-type BST (U 'E Nd))

    (define-struct Nd
      ([root : Integer]
       [lsub : BST]
       [rsub : BST]))

(: leaves : BST -> (Listof Integer))
;; return the list of leaves from left to right
;; note: the result must be strictly ascending
(define (leaves x)
  (match x
    ('E '())
    ((Nd ro 'E 'E) (list ro))
    ((Nd ro ls rs)
     (append (leaves ls) (leaves rs)))))
```

The above function however does not work. I get a list of all the leaves but its not ascending. Can someone please help?
I am learning to code at home so don't have access to teachers or mentors.

Comment: It should definitely be ascending, *if* the input is a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) ("BST"). In your previous questions you have posted test inputs that are not binary search trees, and it won't work if they aren't.

Comment: Te default case is missing adding the value of this node. eg. `(append (leaves ls) (cons ro (leaves rs)))`.

Comment: @Sylwester That's not a leaf value.

Comment: @molbdnilo your right. I missed that OP only wanted the leafs even when mentioned several times 

Comment: Which language setting are you using?  Is it `#lang typed/racket` ?